# Rules for $(x^a)^b$ - complex number.

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation

How potentiate $(x^a)^b$ for complex numbers?

Comment: in this case $x$ is complex number?

Comment: See for example [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/476968/complex-power-of-a-complex-number) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2914/how-to-combine-complex-powers) or [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2903/why-cant-i-combine-complex-powers). Just search on-site for "complex powers" and you will find plenty more.

Comment: see this - http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593907/how-to-prove-that-every-number-to-the-power-of-any-other-numbers-can-be-express/593924#593924